# what's a .NET way of doing this string code (without using InStr)?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to extract the date from this string. It seems like there should be a way to do this without using InStr. Any ideas from anyone on a more .NET way of doing this?

The string would be like:
"asdf asdf asdf asdf effective 4/25/2017 then more asdfasdfasdfasdfasdf "

```
If myString.ToLower.Contains("effective") Then
    Dim s As String = myString.ToLower
    Dim i As Integer = InStr(s, "effective")
    If i > 0 Then
        s = s.Substring(i + 9)
        Dim e As Integer = InStr(3, s, "/20")
        If e > 0 Then
            s = Strings.Left(s, e + 4)
            If IsDate(s) Then
                datEffect = CDate(s)
            Else
                datEffect = InputBox("Enter the Effective Date")
            End If
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: I'd suggest using regex, it'd look cleaner and work for different dates

Comment: [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx) is the equivalent of InStr. I think one is 0 index while the other is 1 index (-1 will be not found).

Comment: @the_lotus yeah the index will be one less in `IndexOf`.